# unwanted 2 times style element with php page

Tags: php, html, css

If I look at the elements, I see 2 times a style:

[image]

I was wondering, how can I prevent this?

This is my code:

```
<?php    
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');    
?>    
<html>
    <head>    
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
        <style type="text/css"> 
            body {
                overflow: hidden;
                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            }    
        </style>
    </head>
</html>    
<?php
   // more php code here
?>
```

Comment: It is because you have two "style"-blocks on your site. One of them is the font, the other is the style defining the body. This should be no issue.

Comment: verry strange, you sure you saved and opened the right file? also why is seccond style empty? sorry the questions in the question, but if I copy paste your code everything is fine

Comment: @OptimusCrime: One is a `link`, the other is a `style` element. Without some JS magic (which I don't see here), the `link` won't turn into a `style`.

Comment: @clankill3r: From what did you create the screenshot of the source code? From viewing the source of the delivered page, or from the “generated” DOM tree (e.g with Firebug)?

Comment: @lxg frim the DOM tree with chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely inserted by an extension in your browser. Google Chrome has certain extensions that do this, for example.

If you look at the source code, it probably isn't there.

You can check the source in Chrome using the shortcut CTRL + U for windows or ALT + CMD + U on mac.

Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i checked in safari and there all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you opened the same file.

> Please provide me the Dom element which is showing two styles.